# What is the subscription stanza should be sent from my .net app to get XMPP notification from GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

Quick question: What is the subscripiton stanza should sent from my .net app to GAE app.
Background is : 
I want to have a google app engine app act as a Web end point which receives notifications from Google Mirror SDK by JSON over HTTP and relays notification back to the subscribed XMPP clients. From Google App Engine, it sends invitation and sends messages that can be seen from Google Talk client on my windows system. I want to make my .net app similar to Google talk client, i'm trying with agXMPP library, after sending subscription stanza, it throws exception and disconnects the connection.
What is the correct subscription stanza i should send?

I'm sending:

```
 <iq to="user_name@gmail.com" id="agsXMPP_1" type="set">
   <subscribe xmlns="google:push">      
   <item from="test_appid.appspot.com" channel="test_appid.appspot.com" />
   </subscribe>
 </iq>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself and figure it out. Just accept the invitation and send IQ object like this after opening the connection:
            IQ iq = new IQ();
            Jid jid = new Jid("app-id@appspot.com");

```
        iq.To = jid;
        iq.From = _bareJid;
        XmppCon.Send(iq);
```

It worked.